# Python 2.5 time.time() as decimal

Tags: python

Is it possible to receive the output of time.time() in Python 2.5 as a Decimal?

If not (and it has to be a float), then is it possible to guarantee that inaccuracy will always be more than (rather than less than) the original value. In other words:

```
>>> repr(0.1)
'0.10000000000000001' # More than 0.1 which is what I want

>>> repr(0.99)
'0.98999999999999999' # Less than 0.99 which is unacceptable
```

Code example:

```
import math, time

sleep_time = 0.1

while True:
  time_before = time.time()
  time.sleep(sleep_time)
  time_after = time.time()
  time_taken = time_after - time_before
  assert time_taken >= sleep_time, '%r < %r' % (time_taken, sleep_time)
```

**EDIT:**

Now using the following (which does not fail in testing but could still theoretically fail):

```
import time
from decimal import Decimal

def to_dec(float_num):
  return Decimal('%2f' % float_num)

sleep_time = to_dec(0.1)

while True:
  time_before = to_dec(time.time())
  time.sleep(float(sleep_time))
  time_after = to_dec(time.time())
  time_taken = time_after - time_before
  assert time_taken >= sleep_time, '%r < %r' % (time_taken, sleep_time)
  print 'time_taken (%s) >= sleep_time (%s)' % (time_taken, sleep_time)
```

Comment: To help us give sensible answers, could you explain the real purpose behind this requirement?

Comment: It is for a timing function which needs to register a time before and after a call that may sleep. So `assert time after - time before >= sleep time`, which is not always the case with floats. Remembering that time.time() gives you a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply multiple `time.time()` by some value to get the precision you want (note that many calls can't guarantee sub-second accuracy anyways).  So,

```
startTime = int(time.time() * 100)
#...
endTime = int(time.time() * 100)
```

Will satisfy your condition that `endTime - startTime >= sleepTime`

Answer (score 1):

You could format your float value as so:

```
>>> '%.2f' % 0.99
'0.99'
```

See [Python's String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: This works well for output, but if you need to store the values, then compare, you'll want to make sure to store them as `int` to avoid imprecision

Comment: This question has more to do with representation error than imprecision. See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

Answer (score 0):

> It is for a timing function which needs to register a time before and after a call that may sleep. So time after - time before >= sleep time, which is not always the case with floats.

I think your requirements are inconsistent. You seem to want to call the same function twice, and have the first call round the result *downwards*, and the second call to round the result *upwards*.

If I were you:

1. I'd time many calls instead of just one.
2. When drawing any conclusions I'd take into account the resolution of the timer and any floating-point issues (if relevant).

Comment: Its true that the requirements can be construed as inconsistent. However from testing if just before_time rounds upwards the assertion never fails; i.e. -before -after, +before +after, +before -after all pass and -before +after fails.